# AJAX call successful, but not replacing div as expected

Tags: php, ajax

After much Googling, I'm on the cusp of success (I think).

I have a fairly large page, overview.php that contains the following snippets:

```
<script>
  function getSummary(id)
  {
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '_table_category.php',
       data: "catid=" + id, 
       success: function(data) { 
            $('#summary').html(data);
            alert('Successfully called');
         },
         error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
             alert('Exception:', exception);
         }
     });
  }
</script>
```

Down the page, I iterate over an array and populate a table. The first column is as follow:

```
<td> <a onclick="getSummary('<?php echo $expenses[$k]['categoryid']; ?>')"> <?php echo $expenses[$k]['shortdesc']; ?> </a>  </td>
```

And then further down on the page, there is a div that will contain the details:

```
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header"> <h3 class="box-title"> Details </h3> </div>
        <div class="box-body"> 
          <div id="#summary"> Select a category to see the details. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

No errors upon loading the page, nor by clicking on the 'link'. If I click on the link, it pops up with the 'Successfully called' alert as expected.

Looking in the Network tab of the developer tools in Chrome, it calls the _table_category.php page (with a value for catid), and if I click on the link it lists (for example _table_category.php?catid=35), the HTML in the preview pane is correctly formatted HTML. 
If I then paste the HTML inside the div manually, it looks exactly as hoped.

This makes me think I am missing something fairly obvious and I am just not actually replacing the div with the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your div has a bad ID.

```
<div id="#summary">
```

It should just be:

```
<div id="summary">
```

The `#` is just there in the selector (it's used to specify "select by ID").

Comment: Just vote to close as a typo for trivial errors like this.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks, will mark as answered as soon as the timer allows.